# dbus-glib i can't figure out how to receive a{sv}

Tags: glib, dbus

i'm using dbus-glib to get the currently playing file name in smplayer2 .
and i got 
http://bpaste.net/show/161995/
i trying to use the Get method to get the Metadata(type="a{sv}" )property ,

i write some code like this 
    DBusGConnection *bus;
    GError *error = NULL;

```
bus = dbus_g_bus_get (DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &error);

DBusGProxy *smplayer;
smplayer= dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name (bus,
        "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.SMPlayer2",
        "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2", 
        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties");

GValue *Metadata;
dbus_g_proxy_call (smplayer, "Get", &error,
        G_TYPE_STRING,"org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player",
        G_TYPE_STRING,"Metadata", G_TYPE_INVALID,
        G_TYPE_VALUE, &Metadata, G_TYPE_INVALID);
```

but Metadata seen to be empty.

can  anyone  know this , please ,
any help will appreciate

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to check the value of Metadata?

Comment: my code is here http://bpaste.net/show/172997/ but can't get the Metadata , and i still don't know how to get it , i really want some example code to get the a{sv} data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [freedesktop.org DBusBindings page](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/), DBus-GLib is obsolete.  Good catch @nemequ

The replacement is GDBus (D-Bus support in GLib) which provides [high level](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/2.26/gdbus-convenience.html) and [low level](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/2.26/gdbus-lowlevel.html) API.  I would strongly recommend migrating over as the new API provides methods that make working with DBus much easier.

I've only worked with the dbus low level API, not glib but I think [g_dbus_gvariant_to_gvalue](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.29/gio-D-Bus-Utilities.html#g-dbus-gvariant-to-gvalue) is what you need.  Note that this method is provided in the new API GDBus, not the one that you're using DBus-GLib. The `get` method returns a variant type, which is a container of sorts. You need to get the value out of the container.

[The API Reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.29/pt02.html) is full of good stuff. Check there if the above doesn't do the trick. Hope that helps

Comment: He is using dbus-glib, not gdbus.

Comment: thank you very much ! i don't know dbus-glib is obsolete , i kind of mix dbus-glib and GDBus , and i can get Metadata now with this code http://bpaste.net/show/173369/